# MySQL Query with the count, group by

Tags: mysql, group-by

Table: statistics

```
id | user  | Message
----------------------
1  | user1  |message1 
2  | user2  |message2
3  | user1  |message3
```

I am able to find the count of messages sent by each *user* using this query.

```
select user, count(*) from statistics group by user;
```

How to show *message* column data along with the count? For example

```
user | count | message
------------------------
user1| 2     |message1
             |message3
user2| 1     |message2
```

Comment: what is size of message column?

Comment: message varchar(100)

Comment: Is your sample data and expect result correct? because `message3` is for `user1`.

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: @D-Shih mysql version is 5.6 and yes sample data is correct. This is messages sent by the user. user1 has sent 2 messages: message1 and message3.

Comment: Please mention why downvote? It helps me to correct my mistake in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to show `Count` by `user`, which `message` sent by `user`.

If your mysql version didn't support window functions, you can do subquery to make `row_number` in select subquery, then only display `rn=1` users and count

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   id INT,
    user VARCHAR(50),
  Message VARCHAR(100)
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES(1,'user1'  ,'message1'); 
INSERT INTO T VALUES(2,'user2'  ,'message2');
INSERT INTO T VALUES(3,'user1'  ,'message3');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT (case when rn = 1 then user else '' end) 'users',
       (case when rn = 1 then cnt else '' end) 'count',
       message
FROM (
  select 
      t1.user, 
      t2.cnt, 
      t1.message,
      (SELECT COUNT(*) from t tt WHERE tt.user = t1.user and t1.id >= tt.id) rn
  from T t1
  join (
    select user, count(*) cnt
    from T
    group by user
  ) t2 on t1.user = t2.user
) t1
order by user,message
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2653f/29/0)**:

```
| users | count |  message |
|-------|-------|----------|
| user1 |     2 | message1 |
|       |       | message3 |
| user2 |     1 | message2 |
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select user, count(*) as 'total' , group_concat(message) from statistics group by user;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `join` the result of your `group by` with the full table (or vice versa)?

Or, depending on what you want, you could use `group_concat()` using `\n` as separator.

Comment: can you explain how join will work in this case, if user is not to be repeated

Comment: @Shubham See D-Shih's new answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use Group_concat

```
select user, count(0) as ct,group_concat(Message) from statistics group by user;
```

This will give you message in csv format

**NOTE: GROUP_CONCAT has size limit of 1024 characters by default in mysql.**

For UTF it goes to 1024/3 and utfmb4 255(1024/4).

You can use group_concat_max_len global variable to set its max length as per need but take into account memory considerations on production environment

```
SET group_concat_max_len=100000000
```

Update:

You can use any separator in group_concat

```
Group_concat(Message SEPARATOR '----')
```

Comment: Would it be possible to get output in next row instead of csv since "message" column is already having "comma" and it is difficult to parse by group_concat's "comma".

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping with self-join:

```
select s1.user, s2.cnt, s1.message
from statistics s1
join (
  select user, count(*) cnt
  from statistics
  group by user
) s2 on s1.user = s2.user
```